# Are the contents of my wpa_supplicant.conf correct for WPA3-Personal authentication?

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I use the latest kernel of Debian 12 a.k.a. Bookworm and ask for your advice if the contents of wpa_supplicant (see below) are correct, relevant details are missing or some of the contents ought to be deleted.

Below is my version of /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf to connect my computer to a wireless router that uses WPA3-Personal authentication only.

```
# Connections to pure WPA3-Personal access points

# MAIN section

# ISO/IEC alpha2 country code in which the device is operating

country=us

# Giving configuration update rights to wpa_cli

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel
update_config=1

# According to Archlinux wiki, Intel WiFi 6 cards may need sae_pwe=1 in the main (non network) section of the config file

sae_pwe=1


# NETWORK section

network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    key_mgmt=SAE
    sae_password="the.literal.wifi.password"
        ieee80211w=1
}

group=CCMP
pairwise=CCMP
```

Questions:

(1) Should I set the value of ieee80211w to be 1 or 2?

(2) Are group=CCMP and pairwise=CCMP required?

P.S.: Except for Archlinux's wiki titled [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wpa_supplicant), in which a small sub-section is dedicated to WPA3-SAE, the following online articles do not provide examples of wpa_supplicant.conf with WPA3-Personal authentication:

[wpa_supplicant.conf(5) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/wpa_supplicant.conf)

[wpa_supplicant.conf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_6/+/froyo/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf)

Thank you for your help.

*Edited for clarity: All my hardware and software do support WPA3-Personal and Wi-Fi 6. My computer has an Intel Wi-Fi 6 chipset that supports WPA3-Personal.*

Comment: WPA3 requires hardware and software support. Are you positive that your hardware supports it?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, all my hardware and software support WPA3-Personal.